# Showing data in a heirarchical order using angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, group-by, angular-filters

I have few data in my database. For example :-

```
Labels        Type1   Type2    Type3

p1      EG  CL  val1
p1      EG  CL  val2
p1      EG  CL  val3
p1      EG  EA  val4
p1      EG  EA  val5
p1      EG  EA  val6
p1      EG  MA  val7
p1      EG  IC  val8
p1      EG2 CL  val9
p1      EG2 CL  val10
p1      EG2 CL  val11
p1      EG2 EA  val12
p1      EG2 EA  val13
p1      EG2 EA  val14
p1      EG2 MA  val15
p1      EG2 IC  val16
// To separate p1 and p2 // Intentionally
p2      EG  CL  val1
p2      EG  CL  val2
p2      EG  CL  val3
p2      EG  EA  val4
p2      EG  EA  val5
p2      EG  EA  val6
p2      EG  MA  val7
p2      EG  IC  val8
p2      EG2 CL  val9
p2      EG2 CL  val10
p2      EG2 CL  val11
p2      EG2 EA  val12
p2      EG2 EA  val13
p2      EG2 EA  val14
p2      EG2 MA  val15
p2      EG2 IC  val16
```

I am reading this data from database using C# and then i have to show this in a UI in a heirarchical order like below.

```
p1
    EG  
        CL  
            val1
            val2
            val3
        EA  
            val4
            val5
            val6
        MA
            val7
        IC  
            val8
    EG2
        CL
            val9
```

and so on..

Actually i am showing the data using panel head and panel body with an expand/collapse button.

**Problem :-**

I am able to read the rows from database but i dont know how to use the angular filters to properly groupby the data in my ng-repeat.

Also suggest me if the groupby thing can be done in database and then showing that data directly on the UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should build heirarchical data from C# and then using angular tree to show it. For example: https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example

Comment: @thangcao, thanks alot. It really helped me. Now i am able to show the heirarchical data with additional feature i.e. dragable which i was looking for.
But the problem is now how to prepare heirarchical data from database using C# ?
Can you please share any useful link related to this ?